# Regular Expression Support in MFC Native Appli

Tags: c++, regex, winapi, mfc

I know MFC doesn't have built-in regex class.  Is there any easy-to-use class lib for adding regex to my native win32 c++ application?  I heard of boost.  I don't have time to evaluate each class lib in detailed.  Is it simply a class lib immedately usable just like java regex classes?  I'm looking simple out of the box solution.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The Boost regex library is good, and has support for MFC's `CString`: see [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/mfc_strings.html) for information and examples. To get started, either download the pre-compiled 32-bit libraries from [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download) or read the [Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html) page.

I haven't used the standard C++ regex library included in VS2008 SP1 or VS2010, but as they are included with Visual Studio they'll be an easier to use out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but [ATL seems to have some form of regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/magazine/cc163755%28en-us%29.aspx).  (search for regex on the page, the page is a mess).

I also know the VS2008 TR1 extras have TR1 `<regex>` functionality. VS2010 also has this header and implementation (maybe in updated form to conform to a later standard). These are of course available through Standard C++: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx)

Keep in mind the TR1 implementation is still buggy, but it might not be for your case `;)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/) library is very nice. It's a *C language* implementation, but since it has a very simple interface, it is easy to wrap in a C++ class.